# Javascript Variables in Rails Assets

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, assets

I have a Rails 4 app. I define a variable `var a = 1` in `app/assets/javascripts/a.js`. Then I'd like to use that variable in `app/assets/javascripts/b.js`, but whenever I use `a` in `b.js`, it says it's undefined. Why?
Thanks.

Comment: If you look at your page source, in what order are these two files included? Assuming both are being merged into your application.js, I'd open that docuement via your browser's "View Source" option, and make sure 'a' really is defined before it is referenced in 'b.js'.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure a.js is required before b.js:

```
//= require a
//= require b
```

If using `require_tree .` files will be required in alphabetical order (which works in your example: a, b)

**EDIT**: Didn't notice before, but @ConnorCMcKee answered in a comment before me.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did what you said (`//= require a` before `//= require b`) but it didn't solve the problem. The two files are https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-agency/gh-pages/js/classie.js and https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-agency/gh-pages/js/cbpAnimatedHeader.js and in line 30 it complains that `"classie" is not defined`.

Comment: JS is not my strong, but it appears to me `classie` is being defined inside an anonymous function (the one you pass `window` to), so it won't be visible outside of this scope. Try definint a variable outside of this function and see if that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

as @leito said your variable is local one and needs to be declared global

use `window.classie` instead of `var classie`